# Windows 10 - Updating Background for Start Icons/Pins

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu, start-screen, pin

Requesting information on how to change background color of Start Pins in Windows 10. An example would be changing from the blue background to black (example image: VS Code with black and VS 2017 with blue/defined color). Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Visual Studio, or is that just an example?  If it’s just an example, you probably shouldn’t mention it in the title and tags.  And if you are asking specifically about Visual Studio, you should say so.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: If the app is simple Win32 app then the color depends on Settings > Colors. If that app is UWP then the color property is defined in AppxManifest.xml file of that Appx package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Biswapriyo was correct! Thank you!

I was able to change the color by doing the following:

1) Right-clicking the pin

2) Select "More" -> "Open file location"

3) Right-click the Visual Studio 2017 icon and open "Properties"

4) Click the "Open file location" button

5) Search for "AppxManifest.xml" in the File Explorer

6) Opened all four available files in an editor (e.g. VS Code)

7) Change the BackgroundColor value from "Transparent" to "#2D2D30"

8) Saved changes as administrator

9) Re-pinned the app an it worked!

10) Click the "Apply" button in the Properties menu from Step 3

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there any UWP version of Visual Studio?

Comment: 2017 appears to be. My version is Professional, though I don't think it matters.

Comment: @Biswapriyo from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how you can change the color of individual tiles, the answer is you can't.
However, you can change the color of ALL tiles in the Windows Settings:
You do this in *Settings* > *Personal settings* > *Colors*

Note: The exact names of the menu might be slightly different, I don't have Windows set to English

**UPDATE:** I found [an unofficial method](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/) that can be used to change the background color of individual tiles. It only works for .EXE's though.
I haven't tested this myself, but it should do what you are asking.

Comment: I'm looking to change the color of the individual tiles. Thanks for the info though!